# Implicit ownership within Rust

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

I expect the following code to not compile due to outliving but it works.

```
fn main() {
    let x;
    {
        let y = &13;
        x = y;
    }
    println!("{}", x); 
}
```

```
13
```

The same example with composite types raises an error as I wanted.

```
fn main() {
    let x: &Box<i32>; 
    {
        let y = &Box::new(13);
        x = y; 
    }
    println!("{}", x); 
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> ./life_1_2.rs:4:18
  |
4 |         let y = &Box::new(13);
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
5 |         x = y;
6 |     }
  |     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
7 |     println!("{}", x);
  |                    - borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

A typical outliving example gives an error too:

```
fn main() { 
    let x;
    {
         let y = 13;
         x = &y; 
    }
    println!("{}", x); 
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
 --> ./life_1.rs:5:13
  |
5 |         x = &y;
  |             ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
6 |     }
  |     - `y` dropped here while still borrowed
7 |     println!("{}", x);
  |                    - borrow later used here
```

It seems like Rust automatically manages the assignment through ownership instead of borrowing when dealing with primitive types.
Does anybody know if it is correct an in such case why? Unfortunately I did not find any answer.

Comment: I'll wait for the experts to confirm, but if ```13``` is a constant, so wouldn't the lifetime of ```&13``` be ```'static``` ?

Comment: This is demonstrably the case. You can do `let y: &'static i32 = &13`, but `let y: &'static Box<i32> = &Box::new(13)` errors with a temporary which is freed.